# Trying to create a computed column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a computed column in SQL Server.

This is script to create column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceID] AS (('INV' + FORMAT(GETUTCDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd')) + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT([VARCHAR](20), [ID]), (7))),
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_Invoice_CreatedOn]  DEFAULT (getutcdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

It will return a value for `InvoiceId` column like this:

```
ID  InvoiceID            Name    CreatedOn
--- -------------------- ------- -----------------------
1   INV201705090000001   amki    2017-05-09 13:11:06.790
2   INV201705090000002   amkit   2017-05-09 13:11:26.600
3   INV201705090000003   amkit3  2017-05-09 13:11:32.397
4   INV201705090000004   amkit6  2017-05-09 13:11:35.070
```

But I want to modify it more.

When server date changes, then again it start from 1.

This is my expected output.

```
ID  InvoiceID            Name    CreatedOn
--- -------------------- ------- -----------------------
1   INV201705090000001   amki    2017-05-09 13:11:06.790
2   INV201705090000002   amkit   2017-05-09 13:11:26.600
3   INV201705090000003   amkit3  2017-05-09 13:11:32.397
4   INV201705100000001   amkit6  2017-05-10 13:11:35.070
5   INV201705100000002   amkit6  2017-05-10 13:11:35.070
6   INV201705110000001   amkit6  2017-05-11 13:11:35.070
```

As you can see from above result, It again start from **1** where date change from **20170509**  to  **20170510**.

If it can not be done using computed column, Then is there any other way I can achieve this.

I know there are many post related to how to create computed column. But I don't how to make it again start from 1 when date changes.

Comment: Could you create a function to return a count of the days invoices?

Comment: @apc: I didn't get you. what do you mean by count of days .

Comment: I don't think ,this can be achieved by computed columns.you can use a view

Comment: Create a function which takes the created on date and ID and returns a count of the rows for that date and with a smaller ID, then +1 to get then end of you invoice no.

Comment: apc has the right of it.  You should be able to do this with a custom function.

Comment: Thinking about it more, this shouldn't really be a calculated column as you will have to look at the existing data in the table and if a row is removed then the invoice ID will change. You would be better of performing this calculation within the stored prodedure which does the insert or in an INSERT TRIGGER and instead of COUNT use RANK and get the highest (or get the last inserted and substring the numeric part and +1)

Comment: @apc: yes. `SP` is last option. But I was trying to achieve it using computed column.

Comment: As this is an Invoice ID, I would assume you would never want it to change, therefore you shouldn't use a computed column as changes to the data would cause this to change. Also this is not good for performance as the ID would be caculated everytime you view the table.
You options are therefore:
INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger
Stored Procedure to perform the insert (calculating the new ID)
Create a function to calculate the ID (making sure it is unique and consecutive) which you can call as the Default Value for the column

Comment: I strongly agree with @apc on this. A computed column is not an appropriate choice for data that should be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with **TheGameiswar** on this one.  I think a view (or simple query) would be best

**Example**

```
Select ID
      ,Invoice = concat('INV',convert(varchar(8),CreatedOn,112),right('0000000'+convert(varchar(5),Row_Number() over (Partition By convert(date,CreatedOn) Order by CreatedOn,ID)),7))
      ,Name
      ,CreatedOn
 From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

**After Update**

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you have ID as a secondary order by on the Row_Number or will createdon be 100% unique 100% of the time?

Comment: Risk is minor but I'd hate to have invoice numbers change on an ID...  that would lead to some major headache's; though I don't like calculating this on the fly.  Once an invoice number is assigned it should be Done, and not changed.  I'd prefer a trigger for this on create and once generated a the value should never change (especially once sent to the customer!)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti : Thanks your answer. But I need a small suggestion here. I don't want to create Invoice number on fly. I want to store in a column. So what be better approach here. Using `trigger` or `SP` considering performance as There will lots of records inserted daily. avg (70000 records per day)

Comment: @AmitKumar Hard to say.  You have a respectable volume going in, but the real question is how many updates.  Personally, tend to I avoid triggers.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti : No. Once record is inserted then there is no update operation.

Comment: @AmitKumar OK, I misunderstood the premise.  If it was my database, I would opt for sp over a trigger.  But that is just a reflection of my personal dislike of triggers.